# Dynamic SQL query which calculates the revenue generated for first X days since the onboarded Date

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamicquery

Consider the following datatables.
**1. Customer Table**

| id | name | onboarded_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxx | 2021-10-01 |
| 2 | yyyy | 2021-10-02 |
| 3 | zzzz | 2021-10-05 |

**2. Revenue Table**

| id | customer_id | date | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-02 | 300 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-10-03 | 200 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-10-07 | 100 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-10-10 | 100 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021-10-12 | 300 |
| 7 | 3 | 2021-10-14 | 600 |

How can we write a single dynamic query which calculates for each customer - the revenue generated for first 10 days from onboarded date (considering onboarded date as the start date)

Note: The start date and end date for each customer to calculate the total revenue is dynamic here

**Expected Result:**

| id | name | start_date | end_date | total_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxx | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-10 | 100 |
| 2 | yyyy | 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-11 | 600 |
| 3 | zzzz | 2021-10-05 | 2021-10-14 | 1000 |

Comment: Join by customer_id and date between onboarded_date and onboarded_date plus the period length, then aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dynamical query you may use one with a parameter.

```
select c.id,
       c.name,
       c.onboard_date start_date,
       date_format(c.onboard_date + DAYS, '%Y-%m-%d') end_date,
       sum(revenue) revenue
  from customers c
  join revenue r
    on r.customer_id = c.id
 where r.date between c.onboard_date and c.onboard_date + DAYS
 group by c.id,
       c.name,
       c.onboard_date;
```

In your code you can just replace "DAYS" with some binding parameter.

See the [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usu3XK7Gn8gGqQnusmCiLk/0) for details

Comment: Thank you for the help, this easily summarises the result needed